# How would I send a username/password from a Socket-run Java Client to a Server, verify the details, and then send a boolean result back to the client?

Tags: java, sockets, server

I've been working on a university project for a bit where I essentially coded a GUI along with a few other features on it. Recently, we've been tasked with implementing a server/client communication on the application, and the topic hasn't really been explained very well to us so I have been struggling. My idea for the implementation is to take the username & password that the client provides at the login screen, send it to a Server class, verify the details, and then send a boolean value of either true or false, depending on whether or not they have the correct details. This hasn't worked, and I don't believe the username/password test variables in the server class take on any values. I will share the relevant snippets of code from both the Client & Server class down below.

**Client Part:**

```
private void loginMessage() {
        /*
         * This is the default login message that will be displayed. We could add
         * checkers and such to the information we receive from the username/password
         * fields, however that is outside of the scope of our current homework
         * assignment. I did, however, make sure to store the username in a string and
         * personalize the welcome message.
         */
        String uName = txtUsername.getText();
        try {
            dout.writeUTF(uName);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        String password = new String(usPassword.getPassword());
        try {
            dout.writeUTF(password);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        try {
            boolean loginSuccess = din.readBoolean();
            if (loginSuccess) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                        "Thank you for logging in " + uName
                                + ". You will now get redirected to our Customer Zone, where you can make purchases. Press OK to continue.",
                        "Success!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                finished = true;

            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                        "Error. Either your username or password is incorrect. Please try again.", "Error",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

    private void cancel() {
        /*
         * This is the cancel operation. We will close the application when the cancel
         * option is selected.
         */
        System.exit(1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 7000);
            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(in);
            // send a message from client to server
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(out);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        // We define a new MyApplication object in order to run our application.
        MyApplication x = new MyApplication();
        Progress a = new Progress();
        Secondpage s = new Secondpage();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(x);
        t1.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        a.start();
        try {
            a.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        s.start();
        try {
            s.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

**Server Part:**

```
public class MyServer {
    Socket serverSocket;
    BufferedReader br;
    FileReader fr;
    static String uname;
    static String pwd;
    static String filepath = "login.txt";
    static String sep = ",";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7000);
            System.out.println("Waiting for a client...");
            Socket mySocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("I have a client");
            DataInputStream clientIn = new DataInputStream(mySocket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream clientOut = new DataOutputStream(mySocket.getOutputStream());
            uname = clientIn.readUTF();
            pwd = clientIn.readUTF();
            System.out.println("I have a username " + uname + pwd);
            boolean verif = verifyUserLogin(uname, pwd, filepath, sep);
            clientOut.writeBoolean(verif);
            System.out.println("Username: " + uname);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public static boolean verifyUserLogin(String user, String pwd, String fp, String sep) {
        String currentLine;
        String data[];

        try {
            // We use FileReader to read file, and BufferedReader to read character stream.
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(fp);
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
                while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    data = currentLine.split(sep);
                    if (data[0].equals(user) && data[1].equals(pwd)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Now, my issue is I am struggling with sending the login and password strings over to the server. I don't think the username & password variables in the Server class are even holding any values to be honest, and I am unsure of how to fix this. I'm kind of lost, and really need some help. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Does this line print out correct results: `System.out.println("I have a username " + uname + pwd);`  And don't ignore exceptions - at a minimum log the exception message.

Comment: It doesn't print at all, unfortunately. Also, I tried changing the logging mechanism from System.out.println(e.getMessage()); to e.printStackTrace(); and that displayed a different error when I closed the program.

The error seems to refer to when I assign uname and pwd to clientIn.readUTF();

Comment: since you're getting username/password from a form, not terminal, you don't need, these lines ( InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();  DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(in);) in the client app.

Comment: Oh okay, how would I go about sending/receiving data from client-to-server, and server-to-client then if not for the DataInputStream/DataOutputStream?